# How to enter a objetct value in JSF using the same object to list in a DataTable?

Tags: jsf, input, primefaces

well, i have i two beans

### Firstbean

```
private int id;
private String name;
```

getters and setters

### Secondbean

```
private Firstbean fb;
private String x;
private String y;
```

....
getters and setters

that beans i use them in a method to list of object from the DB, and list OK
my problem is for a new entry .... if i put this code

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{beanCuenta.banco.codigo}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione Banco"/>   
                                <f:selectItems value="#{DAOBanco.listar()}" var="ban"
                                               itemValue="#{ban.codigo}" itemLabel="#{ban.nombre}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

here in value of selectOneMenu beanCuenta.banco.codigo doesnt work, but for list in a dataTable works fine.

so a temporaly solution i create a new varable in my secondbean only for register but i dont want it

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{beanCuenta.codigoBanco}">  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione Banco"/>   
                                <f:selectItems value="#{DAOBanco.listar()}" var="ban"
                                               itemValue="#{ban.codigo}" itemLabel="#{ban.nombre}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: also the first web code doesnt render well the selectOneMenu

Comment: ok i fix it, i instanciate the object in the same line i declared it and works

Comment: On SecondBean, you must create FirstBean variable first. What do you mean by "doesnt work"? Do you get an exception or component not rendered at all? Do other primefaces components work?